# How to convert a C# regex to javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, string

**Overview:**

I'm using this regex in server side C# validation code. Now I need to implement the same regex in javascript on the client side. When I define the regex in js the compiler throws syntax errors on the pattern stating there are invalid characters.

```
var urlValidationRegex = /(https?|ftp)://(-\.)?([^\s/?\.#-]+\.?)+(/[^\s]*)?$/;
```

**Resolution Steps:**

I tried adding a `/` to the start and end of the regex pattern, but that throws further syntax errors.

**Question:**

How can i convert this regex to a javascript equivalent?

Comment: You have ``/`` inside, escape them, too: [`/(https?|ftp):\/\/(-\.)?([^\s/?.#-]+\.?)+(\/[^\s]*)?$/`](https://regex101.com/r/cW0jI4/1)

Comment: There are some webs out there to check/validate regex. This one for example https://regex101.com/